# lighttpd default page will not go away

Tags: webserver, lighttpd

I am running a web server using lighttpd, I have changed the default document directory and uploaded my new homepage, but the default page is still all that will load.

I have cleared my browser cache, etc. and even removed the default page from the directory. Nothing.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

In your lighttpd.conf file, find the line which looks something like:

```
index-file.names           = ( "index.php", "index.html",
                               "index.htm", "default.htm",
                               "index.lighttpd.html" )
```

And get rid of the ', "index.lighttpd.html"' part, so that it looks like this:

```
index-file.names           = ("index.php", "index.html",
                               "index.htm", "default.htm")
```

Good luck - I hope that works for you!